# RegisterBundles is losing Bootstrap after send project to IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.Net MVC project using VS2013 and I am using the Bootstrap to make the layout styles. I'm using the `RegisterBundles` to register my CSS and JS. The problem is while I'm developing the styles works very well, but, after compile and send the project to a IIS Server it stop to work and seems lose the styles. I don't know why it is happening.

Notice, using VS2013 I make start the project to test and it start using the `IIS Express` of VS2013 then it works very well, but after compile and send the project to IIS Server it stop to work.

I already have the `Static Content` role enabled on IIS, but it still doesn't works too.

How could I fix this problem ?

**BundleConfig**

```
public class BundleConfig{
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles){

            /************************* BOOTSTRAP ***********************************/
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                                         "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
                                        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                                        "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"
                                        ));
            //********************************************************************/


            /******************************** DATETIME PICKER ********************/
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datetimepicker").Include(
                                        "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
                                        ));
            //********************************************************************/


            /*************************** SELECT2 *********************************/
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/select2").Include(
                                        "~/Content/select2-bootstrap.css",
                                        "~/Content/select2.css"                                              
                                        )); 
            /*******************************************************************/


            /*************************** Lightbox Image Gallery *********************************/
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/lightbox").Include(
                                        "~/Content/lightbox.css"                                          
                                        ));
            /*******************************************************************/




            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",       
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",                        
                        "~/Scripts/CustomValidacoes.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Mascaras").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/Mascaras/jquery.mask.js",
                        "~/Scripts/Mascaras/Mascaras.js"));

            //Datetimepicker
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Datetimepicker").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                        "~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js",
                        "~/Scripts/moment_locale_pt-br.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"
                        ));

            //Lightbox
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Lightbox").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/lightbox.js"));



            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));



        }
    }
```

**Layout HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - InvestimentosUSA.com</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")    
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/CustomStyle.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/datetimepicker")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/select2") 
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/lightbox")   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8JZPv2N9bE0OQABj6hKO9QZb0kH32lHo"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!--/layout pagina principal-->
    @Html.Partial("_Loading")
    @Html.Partial("_Header")
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.Partial("_Footer")


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")   
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/PersistObjects/Usuarios/LoginUsuario.js") 
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was happening because I was compiling on Release and then I made compile on Debug and it finally it worked as I wanted.